# Image height same as article tag

Tags: html, css, image

I have an image tag that appears inside an article tag, like this...

```css
article {
  border: 1px solid;
}

img {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<article>
  <h1>Image title</h1>
  Some text here
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300" alt="">
</article>
```

I want the height of the image to be the same as the height of the rest of the stuff in the article tag (so that the top of the title is at the same line as the top of the image, and the bottom of the text is at the same line as the bottom of the image). I tried adding `height: 100%;` inside `style` but that didn't work. Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Add picture of result what result you want. that will be helpful for others to understand!

Comment: @SadiaYounas added an image in the edit

Comment: @TannerDolby I hope the image explains it?

Comment: Is the textual content a fixed amount or are you trying to write a snippet of code that will work no matter how much textual content is in the article?  You do realize that as the image height increases, so will its width, therefor reducing the width of the content area.  Is the width of the entire article fixed?  Please explain more.

Comment: Totally missed the making the image height the same as the article. Updated my answer.

Answer (score -1):

It depends on the height of the Image. You need to play around with the values, to find a good ratio.

```css
article {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.article-img {
  width: 6em;
}
.article-img > img {
  width: 100%;
}

.article-details {
  padding-bottom: 2em;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;

  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<article>
  <div class="article-img"><img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300" alt=""></div>
  <div class="article-details">
    <div><h1>Image title</h1></div>
    <div>Some text here</div>
  </div>
</article>
```

Comment: did you run your snippet?  the result is not what the OP wants.

Comment: still not what he wants.

Comment: Keep calm. It was still in progress :D

Comment: don't provide an answer that is "still in progress"

Comment: Actually, I just wanted to click the "Run code snippet" but I accidentally clicked the answer button, both are blue. The hand moved faster as the brain thinks, hups :D

Comment: there is no shame in deleting the answer and then posting it again when you have it right.

Answer (score -1):

Provide a height or max-height to the article and make the image relative to the article with a height and max-height of 100%. Without the specified height on the article, the article will stretch to the size of the image if it is larger.

Also, there are some issues with the float that need to be addressed. Apply the "clear fix" method to the article, wrap the h1 and text in a div, and float the div next to the image.

```css
article {
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid;
  position: relative;
}

article:after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

img {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

div {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<article>
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300" alt="">
  <div>
    <h1>Image title</h1>
    <p>Some text here</p>
  </div>
</article>
```